# Safari won't open from one network client

Tags: safari, user-account, server.app, network-user

I have a user who is having difficulty opening Safari on one particular client machine. They have tested it on all other client machines in the same office and it works without issue, but this one machine will not have it. It stopped working half way through the day without any changes taking place.

I initially thought this might be because all user homes are located on a network server running in `Server.app`, but I haven't seen any documentation suggesting that this may be the case.

Steps taken so far:

- [Deleting the saved state and caches.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/178294/apple-safari-mac-os-x-10-10-2-will-not-open)
- [Clearing history, lastsession, metadata cache and cookies.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5191624)
- Restorying the `~/Library/Safari` directory from time machine.
- Restorying the entire `~/Library` directory from time machine.

None of these steps have made any difference, Safari just will not open on this one machine.
Sadly I haven't been able to look in person, and wouldn't know where to begin with diagnosing over the phone without the ability to just poke things. Has anybody come across anything similar to this before or know where to look to try and find the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Alas I never did figure out the cause of this. Due to the nature of where the machine was, I could only work on it for a few minutes at a time in a "test - didn't work - go away and try the fix from a SSH terminal in another room" sort of way.

For the poor unfortunate soul who finds this in the future, the only thing that seemed to fix it was installing a security patch that was waiting to be installed. Issue just completely went away after that and I'm still non the wiser as to the cause.